# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid role NestJs Jest Tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-exception-filters

I have introduced an nest `HTTP exception filter` in the project and included it globally in `main.ts`

```
  const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter(httpAdapter));
```

NestJS Jest tests are failing with below error.

```
[Nest] 13076  - 09/03/2022, 2:16:50 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid role(s): []
AccessControlError: Invalid role(s): []
    at new AccessControlError (/Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/accesscontrol/lib/core/AccessControlError.js:24:28)
    at Object.getFlatRoles (/Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/accesscontrol/lib/utils.js:550:19)
    at Object.getUnionAttrsOfRoles (/Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/accesscontrol/lib/utils.js:739:27)
    at new Permission (/Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/accesscontrol/lib/core/Permission.js:51:43)
    at RolesBuilder.Object.<anonymous>.AccessControl.permission (/Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/accesscontrol/lib/AccessControl.js:481:16)
    at AclFilterResponseInterceptor.intercept (/Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/src/interceptors/aclFilterResponse.interceptor.ts:25:42)
    at /Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:23:36
    at InterceptorsConsumer.intercept (/Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:25:24)
    at /Users/shubhamjain/SJ/Projects/amplication/packages/amplication-data-service-generator/generated/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:60
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

### Edit1

Every Controller's endpoint has something related to using roles.

```
@common.UseInterceptors(AclValidateRequestInterceptor)
  @nestAccessControl.UseRoles({
    resource: "Customer",
    action: "create",
    possession: "any",
  })
  @common.Post()
  @swagger.ApiCreatedResponse({ type: Customer })
  @swagger.ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: errors.ForbiddenException })
  async create(@common.Body() data: CustomerCreateInput): Promise<Customer> {
```

Any pointers to debug this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show more of your code.

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from the `aacesscontrol` library. We'd need more information to help further

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I am new to this project, You can ask me for the specific information you would need and i would be able to share :)